# Interaction within a shell script

Tags: command-line, server, scripts, syslinux

I am trying to install docker on my ec2 instance via a shell script.

I have this in my shell script `sudo apt install docker.io` this is failing as I get a prompt `After this operation, 258 MB of additional disk space will be used.` to which I have to say yes. How can I code the interaction? Is there a way around that?

Comment: Related: [Why apt-get does not ask permission to continue before installing small packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/441793/why-apt-get-does-not-ask-permission-to-continue-before-installing-small-packages)

Answer (score 0):

When I tried your install command it ask me for [J/n] (german version). So I called

```
echo n | sudo apt install docker.io
```

(because I didn't want to install) and it behaved as it was interactively, so accepting the "n" without need to push it. I expect the same for "J". Maybe something similar is working for you.